# How to compute the covariance matrix for a mixture model estimated by the EM algorithm

Tags: missing-data, covariance-matrix, expectation-maximization, fisher-information, finite-mixture-model

I am trying to compute the observed Fisher information matrix for a mixture model estimated by the EM algorithm. My original thought is to simply compute the second derivative of a mixture density. However, I found in the literature that the missing information principle is the standard methodology. I am wondering if it is right to calculate in my way.

I found Louis' paper (Louis 1982) quite helpful. However, I am confused about one sentence below:
[image]
What is a priori expectation here? Is it just the expected fisher information of the observed data?

Besides, when I tried the general equation $I_{Y} = I_{X} - I_{X|Y}$ where $X$ is complete data, $Y$ is observed data, I am wondering the exact form of expectations in $I_{X}$ and $I_{X|Y}$. Are they conditional expectations of the hidden variable given observed data? Because in Louis' paper, $I_{X}$ and $I_{X|Y}$ are computed by means of expected full data conditioned on observed data. Since I want to compute the observed Fisher information matrix, is it possible to directly insert the sample data and the estimated parameters instead of taking the expectation?

Can anyone give me some hints or relevant literature that might help?